# Ethernet port and WiFi adapter not detected, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, usb, ethernet

Excuse me for any newbie mistakes I'm making, this is my first time running any Linux distro. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 off a live USB drive on a Dell Vostro 2510. If I plug an Ethernet cable in, it doesn't show up under network. The cable and connection work fine on other computers, so I'm thinking it's the OS not detecting the port on the computer. The same thing happens with WiFi, the OS doesn't detect the laptop's WiFi adapter.

I've tried disabling and reenabling networking from the taskbar. Here's a screenshot with my network settings: [image: Screenshot]

Here's what I get from ifconfig:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4852 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4852 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:358752 (358.7 KB)  TX bytes:358752 (358.7 KB)
```

I'm left with no way to access the Internet on that machine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you see on taskbar the wifi icon? If yes, click on it & ensure 'Enable Networking' & Enable Wi-Fi is checked. Try this first. Hope it'll helps.

**Start Adding your Ethernet first & set all to automatic settings to see how it works.**

[image: Click Add button to adding new network]

**Click Add button to adding new network**

[image: Select Ethernet & click Create]

**Select Ethernet & click Create**

[image: Checked the box as in picture]

**Checked the box as in picture**

[image: Key in device address(open terminal, type ifconfig & see HWaddr) set to Automatic & checked Default]

**Key in device address(open terminal, type ifconfig & see HWaddr) set to Automatic & checked Default**

Leave the rest & click Save.
**See how it works!**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Networking is enabled already. I turned it off and back on, no change.

Comment: No change means working?

Comment: No change meaning it's still not working; nothing has changed.

Comment: can you edit your questions & paste the screenshot of the event? perhaps we can what's the actual cause of it. Thanks.

Comment: What screenshots should I take?

Comment: the screenshot of your wifi & ethernet settings & if possible. Hope others will help you on this as long as they get noticed on this questions.

Comment: see my edited answers.

Comment: I didn't notice any change, and Firefox still gives me a no connection. Network menu doesn't show a connection, in the settings under last used it says never. The device on the other end of the Ethernet cable doesn't register a connection.

Comment: Should there be something in the Device field when I set up the connection? There's a button that looks like it should be a dropdown, but it's grayed out and can't be clicked.

Comment: I wasn't sure about this. Maybe you can ignore all the proxy settings first. I just re-update again my answers. Wish you luck.

Comment: Ok, I added the results from ifconfig to my question. I don't see any HWaddr.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought it will show the HWaddr which is maybe similar to MAC address. just ignore the HWaddr & try to proceed with my answers. Thanks.

Comment: Still no network connection.

Comment: Why don't you try to install ubuntu on your laptop hard drive or use virtual machines(vm), perhaps? suggestion for vm is virtualbox.

Comment: I'll install Ubuntu on my laptop tomorrow, then see if the issue is only with the USB. Originally I wanted Ubuntu on a USB so I could boot it from any computer, but if it can't work with the hardware, there's not much point.

Comment: yeah! I got your point. but if you are using vm, it would be better since it will bridged the connections from your main machine, thus it'll be better alternative rather than usb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47851/discussion-between-wafie-ali-and-zenon).